# Increase values in MinHeap

Tags: heap, heapsort, min-heap

I have a MinHeap of Integer For Example.
I would like to ask if there is way to make increase for some value from the middle of the heap and still save the heap Sorted correctly .

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're asking. Can you give an example?

Comment: I try to explain again: I have a minHeap of my object and i want to edit a specific object in the heap  and after the edit make a action that the heap still be "sorted" - king of heapify action

Comment: I mean to make Increase Key action in MinHeap

Comment: Okay, so you remove the item, modify it, and then insert it again.

Comment: but in the Heap I can remove only the Min Element. I want to increase on every element

Comment: Are you able to modify the source code of your heap class? This is something that you'd have to add as a special operation. It's not a typical operation for a binary heap.